# CSS Firefox 28 box-shadow color spill

Tags: firefox, colors, css

Does anyone know what happened with the latest Firefox 28 box-shadow? It gives me some color spilling. This never happened before and it doesn't repeat itself in any other browser.

Here is a [live example](http://jsbin.com/wideraya/1/edit?html,css,output)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I am using borders instead to achieve the desired result. Instead of 0 -5px 0 0 #4BF25C, use border-top: solid 5px #4BF25C;

Comment: Interesting approach, but it doesn't give the same result. The idea was to get rid of the top shadow while maintaining the shadow position (the shifting of the shadow wasn't good for me, as I wanted another element connected on top of the first one). I abandoned the initial approach as I found no solution for this kind of problem. Thank you for your reply.